# How to re-parent a bone?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have rigged a gun, but the bones/armature is attached to the wrong bone.

I need to move all the bones which are meant for the gun to a different bone.

Images which explain the problem:

[image]

[image: move here to there]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you mean the way to change parent of a bone:

[image]

Comment: YES . thank you for your kindness and response :)

Comment: How can I change the parent of 100 bones at once?