# How to connect different bone structures from the same armature?

Tags: mesh, bones, transforms, pose-mode

**Hi!**

I'm fairly new to Blender, and I've been having some trouble figuring out how to correctly rig a model.

Inside the model, I have different bone structures for the legs, arms, head and torso. Those all work wonders.

[image: Model]

However, when I pose the torso for example, the root of the other bone structures stay unaffected.

[image: Problem]

Here you can see that when I move the upper torso area, the root of each arm and of the head stay where they were.

I'm sure this question has already been asked a million times but I'm not really sure how to phrase it without going into detail about it.

A solution I thought of was to use Empties, since I heard that those are used in more complex models to control different structures.

[image: Possible Solution]

But I'm now having a hard time figuring out how to parent everything correctly.

Am I on the right track? Has this same question been asked before and I didn't find it? Thanks in advance for your answers.

***P.S.:*** Please do not include the use of anything that can't be exported to a game engine or framework like LibGDX in your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-parent a bone?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6401/how-to-re-parent-a-bone)

Comment: @ShadyPuck I'm sorry but no, it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for asking, I eventually found it. It was actually a lot simpler than I thought! Pretty basic actually, I'm not sure how why it took me so long to notice.

Thanks anyway!

[image: Answer]